# Meaning of すぐ in this sentence

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

> Daughter: 「だって、じゃあたんざくの意味がないじゃん」
> Daughter: But, in that case tanzaku are meaningless aren't they?
> Dad: 「いいのっ」
> Dad: It's okay
> Daughter: 「なにさ、おとうさんは**すぐ**いいのって言うんだから」
> Daughter: What! Because you say it's okay?

I understand すぐ to mean soon/immediately etc. I can't understand what it means in this context.

My guess it that it adds the meaning 'just' as in "am I supposed to believe it's okay **just** because you say so?". But that's a complete guess and the link with 'soon'/'immediately' seems very tenuous.

If further context is needed, these lines follow immediately after [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46770/is-%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE-rhetorical-and-other-conversation-nuances):

Comment: なにさ！ is more like an interjection, like ふんだ！なによ！なんだよ！もう！ etc. Both なにさ and ～だから！ here express 不満、不平、or 苛立ち etc.
(irritation, complaint, dissatisfaction).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「すぐ」, in this context, means "**readily**", "**very easily**", etc.

If you do or say something habitually without thinking, we say you すぐ do or say something.

Comment: So, "because you **keep** saying ..." would be a natural translation?

Comment: @user3856370 It could if the frequency is that high... Besides, there's a hidden misunderstanding taking this から as "because" https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18986/7810